# How to Compare files from two directories and save missing data

Tags: powershell

Hi Guys i need your help in comparison of two files from two directories. Below are the details.

I was not able to post beacause i am getting some format issue while posting so i have described whole issue in the text file which link is mentioned below please help me to solve this issue

[Click here to see the Code](http://www.fileconvoy.com/gf.php?id=gf1142ba50772baa7999557237.588399cae88566793dd9de&sts=14109726625916439225a0083124ef8f59201ce8fe28f5ffcc)

Sorry for bad Coding i am new to Powershell language.

**Edit by TheMadTechnician:** Code from his text file, formatted:

```
cls
$arrFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\data\text\*.txt"
$arrFiles1 = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\data\text\Out\*.txt"
Foreach ($objFile in $arrFiles) {
    Foreach ($objName in $objFile.FullName) {
        $objName
        $Name=$objFile.Name
    }
}
Foreach ($objFile1 in $arrFiles1) {
    Foreach ($objName1 in $objFile1.FullName){
        $objName1
        $Name1=$objFile1.Name
    }
    $FinalGroups=Compare-Object (Get-Content $objName1) (Get-Content $objName) -IncludeEqual | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | select -ExpandProperty inputObject |Out-File C:\$($Name1) -Force
}
```

He has C:\Data\Text and C:\Data\Text\Out. Both have the files A.txt, B.txt, and C.txt. He says that his code works for A.txt but not B.txt or C.txt.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks a lot for posting content here from text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting all files into an array and grouping by file name. Then whenever you have 2 files of the same name get their contents and compare the two. It would look like this (I didn't change your Compare-Object line since you said it works, except to change the objects it compares and the filename that it saves to):

```
cls
$arrFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\data\text\*.txt"
$arrFiles += Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\data\text\Out\*.txt"
Foreach ($objFile in ($arrFiles|group name|where{$_.count -eq 2})) {
    $File1 = Get-Content $objFile.group[0].fullname
    $File2 = Get-Content $objFile.group[1].fullname
    Compare-Object $File1 $File2 -IncludeEqual | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | select -ExpandProperty inputObject | Out-File C:\$($objFile.group[0].name) -Force
}
```

**Edit:** Ok, if it is having that much issue with being an array, we can just make the variable an array first, then add files to it after. Try this:

```
cls
$arrFiles = @()
$arrFiles += Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\data\text\*.txt"
$arrFiles += Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\data\text\Out\*.txt"
Foreach ($objFile in ($arrFiles|group name|where{$_.count -eq 2})) {
    $File1 = Get-Content $objFile.group[0].fullname
    $File2 = Get-Content $objFile.group[1].fullname
    Compare-Object $File1 $File2 -IncludeEqual | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | select -ExpandProperty inputObject | Out-File
```

There I assign the variable to an empty array, then I just add files to the array after that.

Comment: Thanks a Ton it works after changing small thing

Compare-Object $File2 $File1 -IncludeEqual

you are great Appreciated

Comment: Hello my friend. I need your small help. I just come to know that above script is working fine when i used to compare more than one file but when i try to compare single file it's not working. could you please help me to fix this issue ?

Error when comparing 1 file : Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't co
ntain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Comment: Sure, you should be able to cast `$arrFiles` as an array, and it should work fine then. Like `[array]$arrFiles = .....` for line 2.

Comment: It's still not working 

`$arrFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\data\text\*.txt"`
`[array]$arrFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\data\text\Out\*.txt"`